# Reading Response message in modbus using python

Tags: python, modbus, pymodbus

I am trying send the query and get the response message (data) through modbus using python with the help of pymodbus module.

```
response=client.read_holding_registers(19200,126,unit=135)    
print(response)
```

The response that is being printed is the request message sent and the process status. I am interested in reading the data sent from the slave and not the process status. Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `.registers`

Try the following procedure:

```
response = client.read_holding_registers(19200, 126, unit=135)    

if not response.isError():
    print(response.registers)

else:
    # Handle Error
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- `.isError()` method is for *pymodbus 1.4.0* and above.